# My Items button in Experience Editor lists items not locked by anyone

Tags: experience-editor

I am using Sitecore 8.2. Content Authors are complaining that when they click on My Items in EE and then click on Unlock All in LockedItems Dialog that appears, all items dont get unlocked and some items always remain in the Locked Item list. When checked in Content Editor, these items are not locked by anyone. If these items are not locked by anyone, why are they appearing in Locked Items List for content authors? How to prevent this?

Comment: Try rebuilding master index?

Comment: Oops, missed that. Trying right away. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Marek, rebuilding the index fixed it. I wonder why the values were not updated in index with default strategy. Is there an alternative fix for it.

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with `sitecore_master_index`.

Rebuild the index and the issue should be solved.

In some cases, when there are plenty of changes in Sitecore `master` database, there may be some issues resulting in `sitecore_master_index` being out of sync.

One of the possible solutions could be using `async` strategy for `master` database instead of `sync` one.

In nutshell, make sure that you have async strategy defined in your config (it may be there already, but not used):

```
<intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.
          IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
   <param desc="database">master</param>
   <param desc="interval">00:00:10</param>
   <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
</intervalAsyncMaster>
```

and reference it from your index:

```
<index id="sitecore_master_index" ...>
  ...
  <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
    <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster" />
  </strategies>
  ...
</index>
```

You can read more about it here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/173294

And more about strategies in general here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html

Comment: Thanks @Marek - Can you point me where the MyItems references sitecore_master_index. I looked into Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Dialogs.LockedItems.LockedItemsPage and it seems to be looking for locked items in content db instead of index using Client.ContentDatabase.SelectItems("search://*[@__lock='%\"" + Context.User.Name + "\"%']") ?? new Item[0];

Comment: I think I figured it out. We are using a support DLL which uses search pipeline to look for locked items. Search pipeline uses Content Search api to perform the search.

Comment: You're right. It's not the LockedItemsPage which is called to see "My Items" from Experience Editor. Those are content search calls. I don't remember where are they exactly. If my answer was helpful, you may want to mark it as valid.